# Which std types are guaranteed to be empty/null after being used as arg in move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move-semantics

I know `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `weak_ptr` are guaranteed to be empty after used as Rvalue reference argument in the constructor of the same type, but I wonder does standard specifies this for some other `std::` types beside the ones I mentioned.

Please note that I know that elements after move are left in valid but *unspecified* state, I am here interested for which types state is specified.

Comment: `unique_lock` maybe? `future`, `promise`...

Comment: `std::thread` sets other to a default constructed state.

Comment: all the containers? (except those that use small buffer optimization, like std::string)

Comment: @alfC also std::array ;)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, Good catch. Some people don't consider std::array a container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## A rule of thumb

As a rule of thumb: **The move-only types or types with shared reference semantics leave their moved-from object in an empty state.** All other types leave unspecified values.

## Move-only types

Move-only types (which leave moved-from objects in an empty state) are `std::unique_lock`, `std::thread`, `std::promise`, `std::packaged_task`, `std::future`, `basic_filebuf`, `std::basic_ifstream`, `std::basic_ofstream`, `std::basic_fstream`, `std::shared_lock` and `std::unique_ptr`.

## Shared reference semantics

Types with shared reference semantics are `std::shared_future`, and of course `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`. These leave their moved-from objects also in an empty state.

## A notable exception

As I went through the standard library, I found `std::stringstream` and its input-only and output-only siblings (`std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream`) as a notable exception. These classes are move-only, but nothing is being told about the moved-from object upon move-construction. Therefore, the valid-but-unspecified-rule applies. As you see, it's just a rule of thumb, not 100% always correct.

Comment: `shared_lock` is not really shared reference semantics. It's a lot more like `unique_lock` than `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @T.C. Good catch. Fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

Types leaving moved-from objects in "empty" state are smart pointers, locks ([[thread.lock.unique.cons]/21](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.lock.unique.cons#21), [[thread.lock.shared.cons]/21](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.lock.shared.cons#21)), file streams ([[filebuf.cons]/(4.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf.cons#4)), futures ([[futures.unique_future]/(8.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.unique_future#8), [[futures.shared_future]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.shared_future#10)), promises ([[futures.promise]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.promise#6)), packaged tasks ([[futures.task]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.task#futures.task.members-7)), threads ([[thread.thread.constr]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.constr#10)), …

By contrast, templates leaving the moved-from objects with unspecified values are `function` ([[func.wrap.func.con]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.con#6)), `basic_regex` ([[re.regex.construct]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/re.regex.construct#13)), `basic_string` ([[string.cons]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#2)), containers…

Comment: Poor `basic_string`, not considered a container.  *sniff*.

Comment: I mentioned `basic_string` separately since there exists an explicit statement for it, but not for other containers (/cc @T.C. is that right?)

Comment: Right. The container requirements tables don't say anything about the moved-from object, so the default in [lib.types.movedfrom] applies.