# C++: For which objects, being "moved" implies more than "staying valid"?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, move-semantics, std

Given that `a` and `b` are of type `T`, and we have either move construction (`T b(move(a));`) or move assignment (`b = move(a)`). In what cases do we know what the value of `a` will be?

The only one that I know of for sure is `unique_ptr`, in which `a` will become an empty pointer. Is this also guaranteed for `shared_ptr`? Are there any other classes for which the standard guarantees a known value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772219/which-std-types-are-guaranteed-to-be-empty-null-after-being-used-as-arg-in-move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Standard library types**

From the standard N4296,§17.6.3.1, let's `rv` be an rvalue of type `T`,
in Table 20, MoveConstructible requirement and Table 22 MoveAssignable requirement.

After operations:

```
T(rv);
T u =rv;
u = rv;
```

> rv’s state is unspecified [ Note:rv must still meet the requirements of the library component that is using it. The operations listed in those requirements must work as specified
>   whether rv has been moved from or not. — end note ]

It means that at least your moved object is still in a valid state and can be used as any object of its type. But nothing more is required as a library wide requirement. You have to read specific documentation.

For shared_ptr specificaly :

```
shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& r) noexcept;
template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y>&& r) noexcept;
```

> Remark: The second constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless Y* is convertible
>   to T*.
>
> Effects: Move-constructs a shared_ptr instance from r.
>   Postconditions: *this shall contain the old value of r. r shall be empty. r.get() == nullptr.

**Fundamental types and trivially copyables**

The moved object should be unchanged. I am looking for the confirmation in the standard...

**Other types**

At least the programmer of a class shall ensures that an object of this class is destructible after it has been moved!